# Invoking methods with parameters by EL in JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, el, jsf-1.2

I am using a datatable and for each row I have two buttons, an "Edit" and a "Delete".

I need these buttons to be read-only, i.e. disabled, if a certain condition is met for the row in question. I have seen in **JSF 2** that it is possible to pass parameters to method calls. Is there anything equivalent in JSF 1.2?

Ideally what I would like it something like (the looping variable is *loop* and there is another bean, *helper*, which contains the method I would like to invoke):

```
<h:commandButton value="Edit"
                   disabled="#{helper.isEditable(loop.id)}" />
```

In this case it does not make semantic sense to add an *isEditable* attribute to the bean and it is not practical to create a wrapper Object around the bean.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *I have seen in JSF 2 that it is possible to pass parameters to method calls. Is there anything equivalent in JSF 1.2?*

Passing parameters to method calls is **not** specific to JSF 2. It is specific to EL 2.2, which is in turn part of JSP 2.2 / Servlet 3.0 / Java EE 6. JSF 2 just happens to be part of Java EE 6 as well. In other words, if you deploy your JSF 1.2 web application to a Servlet 3.0 compatible container like Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc and your `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 3.0 spec version, then it'll just work out the box for JSF 1.x as well.

If you're however still targeting a container of an older Servlet version, then you need to supply a different EL implementation which supports invoking methods with arguments. One of those implementations is [JBoss-EL](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.0.0.GA/reference/en/html/elenhancements.html) which you can install by just dropping the [`jboss-el.jar`](https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/jboss-releases/org/jboss/seam/jboss-el/2.0.0.GA/jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar) file in `/WEB-INF/lib` of your webapp and adding the following context parameter to the `web.xml`. Here's a Mojarra-specific example ([Mojarra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162190/what-is-mojarra) is the codename of JSF RI):

```xml
<context-param>     
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

If you're using MyFaces as JSF implementation, you need the following context parameter instead:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

#### See also:

- [Invoke direct methods or methods with arguments / variables / parameters in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/invoke-direct-methods-or-methods-with-arguments-variables-parameters-in-el/)