# adding a context-param programmatically?

Tags: jsf, servlets

Is there a way to add a context-param programmatically? I don't want to add in the web-xml.  Specifically I want to do what the answer in this post suggests: [Invoking methods with parameters by EL in JSF 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325298/invoking-methods-with-parameters-by-el-in-jsf-1-2).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

In the servlet's init method, use

```
getServletConfig().getServletContext().setInitParameter("[Parameter name]", "[value]");
```

OR simply

```
getServletContext().setInitParameter("[Parameter name]", "[value]");
```

This must do the trick for you.

For the application load,

In web.xml, when you declare this servlet, provide `<load-on-startpup>` element as 1 for this servlet.

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>TestServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: This approach will however not guarantee that the API which needs the context parameter in question will read it *after* it is programmatically been set.

Comment: It will because the programmer knows the first servlet that will be loaded in the application and in that servlet, init parameters will be set.

Comment: Some APIs (like JSF!) use `ServletContextListener` or `ServletContainerInitializer` to initialize the API and they run long before the first `Servlet` is created.

Comment: So maybe a `ServletContextListener` or the other is the best place to set init parameters?

Comment: By the way `setInitParameter` seems to be only available from Servlet 3.0 onwards