# jsf - el function with bean

Tags: jsf, el, taglib

Hi i can define functions like this for el:

```
    <function>
        <function-name>areAllGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areAllGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</facelet-taglib>
```

but what can i do if i want to use a spring bean with initalised autowired-fields, instead of a plain new instance of an class?

Comment: An EL function does by the way not use a "plain new instance of an class". It's a static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your're using a Servlet 3.0 container which supports EL 2.2 (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc), just do it.

```
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.areAllGranted('someString')}">
```

If your're using an old Servlet 2.5 container which doesn't support it, then install JBoss EL so that you can use the new EL 2.2 syntax. This is answered in detail here: [Invoking methods with parameters by EL in JSF 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325298/invoking-methods-with-parameters-by-el-in-jsf-1-2/8326551#8326551)

Comment: seems to be the simplest soulution