# The function [functionName] must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

Tags: jsf, el, crud, jsf-1.2

I'm using JSF 1.2 and I'm trying to delete and/or update a row in a `<h:dataTable>` whereby the current row is passed as argument of action method.

View:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.list}" var="categoria">
  ...
  <h:column>
    <h:commandButton value="Update" action="#{myBean.updateCat(categoria)}" />
    <h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{myBean.deleteCat(categoria.cod)}" />
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Controller:

```
public void deleteCat(int cod) {
  this.controller.deleteCat(cod);
}

public void updateCat(Categoria cat) {
  this.controller.updateCat(cat);
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> The function deleteCat must be used with a prefix when a
>   default namespace is not specified

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The function deleteCat must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

This error message is typical when the new EL 2.2 feature of invoking bean methods with arguments isn't supported in the current EL environment. That can happen when the current EL environment is actually not comply EL version 2.2 at all. EL 2.2 is part of Servlet 3.0 and thus requires a Servlet 3.0 compatible container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss 6, etc) with a Servlet 3.0 compatible `web.xml` in order to work.

Before EL 2.2, parentheses `()` in EL expressions are by default interpreted as EL function arguments. However EL functions are in turn expected to be referenced by a colon prefix on a taglib namespace like so `#{fn:length(bean.list)}` instead of a period. That explains at least the at first sight rather strange error message.

Given that you're using the legacy JSF 1.2, you're most likely using Servlet 2.5 (Tomcat 6, Glassfish 2, JBoss 4, etc) and thus implicitly also EL 2.1. In order to simulate the new EL 2.2 feature of invoking bean methods with arguments, your best bet is downloading and installing JBoss EL as outlined in this answer: [Invoking methods with parameters by EL in JSF 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325298/invoking-methods-with-parameters-by-el-in-jsf-1-2/8326551#8326551).

Comment: +1 I was just writting something similar, but not as complete, and much less quick...

Comment: Thanks!
Unfortunately I can't update or install any packages in this project so I found a another way.

Comment: @javadev: ......answered in the post below. A full overview of ways can be found in the answer to this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable/

Comment: I have reformulated my question in a new one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186968/pass-parameter-to-a-pojo-method-inside-a-richcolumns

Comment: @BalusC Any hint in my question posted in my above comment?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by binding the datatable with a HtmlDataTable.

Found the solution here:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/497447/JSF/java/delete-row-datatable

```
<h:dataTable id="table" value="#{myBean.list}"
binding="#{myBean.dataTable}"
var="categoria" border="1" styleClass="tabelaFormulario"
headerClass="tabelaTituloFormulario"
rowClasses="tabelaLinhaPar, tabelaLinhaImpar">
```

after that in the bean:

```
private HtmlDataTable dataTable; // + getter & setter
```

and at last I could get data from a selected row by using

```
dataTable.getRowData();
```

and the function is now like:

```
public void deleteCat() {
    this.controller.deleteCat(this.list.get(this.dataTable.getRowIndex()).getCod());
}
```

Thanks anyway, hope it helps someone else...

Comment: It'd be been less verbose if you used `this.controller.deleteCat(this.dataTable.getRowData().getCod());`

Comment: that would need a cast, am I right?
like:
`this.controller.deleteCat((Categoria) this.dataTable.getRowData().getCod());`

Comment: Oh yes, in JSF 1.x you indeed need a cast (in JSF 2.x, that method is generic).