# JSF and JPA with @ManyToMany and custom converter: LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, jpa, jsf-2, many-to-many

I have an `@Entity` with :

```
@Entity
public class Issue implements Serializable
{
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 protected long id; 

 @ManyToOne
 private IssueScope scope;

  //getter/setter
}
```

I use the custom `IssueScopeConverter` to directly use the `IssueScope` with *f:selectItems*. The converter simply

- returns the *id* for the method `getAsString`
- return a newly created object `IssueScope` (with *id* set) for `getAsObject`

This does not raise any problems (and is used many times before with `@ManyToOne`) with *p:selectOneMenu* and similar components with code like this:

```
<h:form id="fScope">
  <p:selectOneButton rendered="true" value="#{issueBean.issue.scope}"
                     converter="IssueScopeConverter">  
    <f:selectItems value="#{issueBean.issueScopes}" var="s"
                   itemLabel="#{s.name}" itemValue="#{s}"/>
  </p:selectOneButton>
  <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{issueBean.save()}"/>
</h:form>
```

Now let's describe my problem: In fact I don't need a `@ManyToOne`, I need a `@ManyToMany` relationship from `Issue` to `IssueScope`:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<IssueScope> scopes;
```

and the XHTML will change to this:

```
<h:form id="fScopes">
  <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{issueBean.issue.scopes}"
                        converter="ErpIssueScopeConverter">  
    <f:selectItems value="#{issueBean.issueScopes}" var="s"
                   itemLabel="#{s.name}" itemValue="#{s}"/>
  </p:selectManyCheckbox>
  <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{issueBean.save()}"/>
</h:form>
```

If I newly create `Issue` and then push the *Save* button to persist the entity this is done without exception. Even selected `IssueScopes` are persisted. Then, if I want to update the entity, I get a `failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed` after pushing the button.

The method `public void save()` in my `@Named @ViewScoped IssueBean` is never entered.

The problem seems to be related to [Lazy loading exception when using JSF Converter (refering to a collection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886390/lazy-loading-exception-when-using-jsf-converter-refering-to-a-collection), but I don't use Seam persistence or have special kind of TransactionInterceptor`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.simtay.com/simple-crud-web-application-with-jsf-2-1-primefaces-3-5-maven-and-jpa/

See if it helps.

Best Regards

Comment: broken link, site simtay not exists any more...

Comment: It's a 2013 answer.

Comment: I know, but that's the only answer when I googled... It is not actual for me now, sorry.