# CDI (Weld) + DeltaSpike + Converstation

Tags: cdi, weld, conversation-scope, deltaspike

I'm currently trying to get CDI (Weld to be more precise) to work with JSF 2 and a long running conversation. I'm starting the conversation in @ConversationScoped my backing bean. I'm also creating a @ConversationScoped entity manager. Sadly the entity I'm editing in my backing bean always get's a *LazyInitializationException* when JSF is trying to write a @ManyToMany mapped field. It seems that the entity get's detached from the entitymanager. In my EntityManagerProducer (see below) the method *createEntityManager()* is not called bevore the LazyInitializationException is thrown, so I'd assume that the entitymanager is actually session scoped. But from what I understand my code does not generate an extended persistence context (since I could not figure how to do that programmatically).

As far as I know DeltaSpike does not yet offer anything for dealing with long running conversations in JSF. Can anybody suggest a method on how to implement long running conversations with CDI using Weld + DeltaSpike (preferably on a Tomcat with weld-servlet)?

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer {
    @Inject
    @PersistenceUnitName("myUnit")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Produces
    @ConversationScoped
    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void closeEm(@Disposes EntityManager em) {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The lazy initialization exception actually does not come from extended persistence contexts or CDI or DeltaSpike. It's simply the same behaviour as described here: [selectManyCheckbox LazyInitializationException on process validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610908/selectmanycheckbox-lazyinitializationexception-on-process-validation)

JSF 2 clones the PersistentBag of my entity causing it to get detached. I also worked around by sprinkling lot's of

```
<f:attribute name="collectionType" value="java.util.ArrayList" />
```

throughout my JSF code.

Answer (score 0):

Having the EntityManager in a conversation scope is only one side of the equation, what scope are your entities in ?

In order to avoid detaching the entities they should also be conversation scoped.

As a side note :
I found that  instead of dealing with entities in a long running scope , it is much easier to reattach them in each request scope.